# regex help about multiple string with ,

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have a string of `tfa_2,tfa_3,tfa_4` and I have a regex of `/^tfa_\d+/`

How can I make it select all the `tfa_1...tfa_999` and disregard the comma?

Thanks.

Comment: I am using a preg_match in php and inputing that regex.

Comment: If the input is guaranteed to contain only `tfa_\d+` tokens, then just use `preg_split` to split at `,`. If it is not, then also split, then filter the list according to the regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Assuming the input contains the exact format `^tfa_\d+(,tfa_\d+)*$` and no limit on the number after `tfa_`

The simplest solution is to use `explode`:

```
$tokens = explode(",", "tfa_2,tfa_3,tfa_4");
```

You can also use `preg_split` or `preg_match`, but they are overkill under this assumption:

```
$tokens = preg_split('/,/', "tfa_2,tfa_3,tfa_4");
```

```
$retcode = preg_match_all('/tfa_\d+/', "tfa_2,tfa_3,tfa_4", $tokens);
```

#### Assuming the input contains the exact format `^[^,]+(,[^,]+)*$`, no quoted token, and no limit on the number after `tfa_`

You need to assert that `tfa_\d+` is not preceded or suceeded by a non-separator (non-comma character) to prevent `htfa_345`, `tfa_456xxx`, `-tfa_34` from being considered a match:

```
$retcode = preg_match_all('/(?<![^,])tfa_\d+(?![^,])/', "tfa_2,tfa_3,tfa_4,htfa_345,tfa_456xxx,-tfa_34", $tokens);
```

Alternate solution, by `explode` the string along `,` and use `array_filter` to filter out unwanted fields:

```
$fields = explode(",", "tfa_2,tfa_3,tfa_4,htfa_345,tfa_456xxx,-tfa_34");
$tokens = array_filter($fields, function ($v) {
    return preg_match('/^tfa_\d+$/', $v) == 1;
});
```

#### Assuming the input contains the exact format `^[^,]+(,[^,]+)*$`, no quoted token, and the number after `tfa_` can only be 1 to 999

Just modify the regex a bit to limit the number (`[1-9]\d{0,2}`):

```
$retcode = preg_match_all('/(?<![^,])tfa_[1-9]\d{0,2}(?![^,])/', "tfa_2,tfa_3,tfa_4456,htfa_345,tfa_456xxx,-tfa_34", $tokens);
```

Similar modification for `explode` + `array_filter` solution:

```
$fields = explode(",", "tfa_2,tfa_3,tfa_4456,htfa_345,tfa_456xxx,-tfa_34");
$tokens = array_filter($fields, function ($v) {
    return preg_match('/^tfa_[1-9]\d{0,2}$/', $v) == 1;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

From the update and the comments,

`/(tfa_\d{1,3})+/g`

In PHP:

```
$re = "/(tfa_\\d{1,3})+/"; 
$str = "tfa_1,tfa_002,tfa_999,tfa_xxx"; 

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

Will match `tfa_1`, `tfa_002`, `tfa_999` but not `tfa_xxx` or `tfa_`

Comment: This regex is too liberal. The OP already provides the format they want `tfa_\d+`.